# Set HTML textbox value from Javascript function return value

Tags: javascript, html

I've two separate HTML file and .js file. I have a calculate method which return the result in the Javascript file.

My question is how to set a textbox value from a Javascript return value. Or at least from a separate Javascript file. Initially I tried below which doesn't work as Javascript and html are separated.

```
function Calculate(ch) 
{
    //...
    document.getElementById('Input').value = resultValue;
}
```

Comment: is 'Input' the id of the textbox?

Comment: Try using an alert box with your method in it. Also setting up a simple example on a site like jsfiddle helps us out a lot.

Comment: can you put up the relevant part of the HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eval is the soution for my problem.
Input.value = eval(Calculate(ch))

Answer (score 0):

try to define the js-file in the bottom of your html-file (near the </body>). if you defined it above the targeted element its unknown. this may help.

felix

Comment: I tried but not working. If I call normal javascript function that's working. So javascript file is properly definied I think but this perticular functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Access textarea contents using the `innerHTML` property, not the `value` property.

```
function Calculate(ch)  {
    //...
    document.getElementById('Input').innerHTML = resultValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried but not working. My "Input" text box is in a table inside a form. Is that an issue?

Comment: Is it an `<input>` or a `<textarea>`?